# Importing Model Class into another app - Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import a model class from another app. My structure looks like the following:

```
mysite/
-- main/
        models.py
-- webshop/
        models.py
```

I'd like to import a model class from my webshop app into the main/models.py. I run the following in my main/models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from ..webshop.models import Item

# Create your models here.
class Test(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my text editor everything seems fine. It finds the appropriate app and finds the model class Item which I need to import there.

When I run makemigrations I am getting the following error:

*ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package*

I've read some other questions on SO on how to make this work but can't figure it out. Tried:

```
mysite.webshop.models import Item
```

aswell. But then I get a: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.webshop'.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`, I'm going to assume in your text editor, your current working directory is `mysite/`. And so using `..webshop.models` you're trying to go up two directories above `mysite/` which is why you're getting the error.

What you need to do is:

```
from django.db import models
from webshop.models import Item
```

Comment: You are completely right!! My text editor was playing with me saying 'unresolved reference webshop'. Thats why I never tried to run makemigrations. But now I did it works like a charm. Thank you sir. 

*Note: I am using Pycharm as a text editor. Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this error message in the editor? *

Comment: You could try File > Invalidate Caches and see if that sorts it out